# How to prepare when entering the field of Psychology from a professional UX background?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory, hci, aging, alzheimer

I come from a Computer Science and professional User Experience (UX) Design background and I'll soon be starting an MSc conversion course in Psychology. My interest is to understand human behaviour and principles of psychological research so that I can apply them in the context of UX, particularly when it comes to people with disabilities and accessibility in general.

What definitive resources on this topic and more specifically on dementia and memory loss in adults through childhood trauma should I be aware of? And why those ones?

Comment: @ConstantinaM Having said that, it may be more worth asking this question over at ux stackexchange rather than here, since it is unlikely that many people here are experienced in or care about UX, whereas it's reasonably likely that people at UX care about psychology, and may therefore be more willing to share their resources and experiences.

Comment: Thank you for editing, Constantina! I have reopened and up voted, although I believe it would still be useful to elaborate on your specific topic of interest. What are you already familiar with, and what is your exact goal? For example, I presume, coming from a UX background, you are already familiar with concepts such as Gestalt psychology and work by Don Norman; highly relevant in the context of UX. In regards to "disabilities and accessibility", is your intent to create assistive technology and/or to better understand such conditions? Any specific diagnosis you are interested in?